# How do I tell Jenkins NOT to stop on fails, or put a condition on exit status?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins shell script launching some python unittest followed by some cypress tests of my streamlit interface.
When all tests pass, everything works as intended, It generates nice html reports.
When any test fails, Jenkins finishes all tests but stops short of making the reports... What use are tests reports then ? ^^

Using

```
set -e
exit /b 0
```

works well when a test fails, but not when they all pass ! It then gives me an error

> exit: Illegal number: /b

I also tried

```
set "errorlevel="
```

but this always marks the build as successful, even when a test failed...

So I tried this

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% gtr 0
then exit /b 0 
else set "errorlevel="
fi
```

But %ERRORLEVEL% is not recognized, so it doesn't work...

Thanks for any help !

Comment: are you running the tests in a different step than the generation of the results?

Comment: Yes, there are the python tests that generate the results in the same step and then the cypress tests that don't. They are followed by mochawesome reports generator, with joining of the json before generating one html report. There's also another step adding screenshots to the report.

Comment: In that case you can pass the sh/bat/powershell step the `returnStatus: true` parameter and apply your own logic to when it should and shouldn't fail.

Comment: Thanks, but I wouldn't know how... Can you provide an example ?

Comment: Are you using a pipeline or a freestyle job?

Comment: It is a Freestyle job.

Comment: Any pointers ? I can't find any instructions on how to pass the returnStatus parameter...

Comment: Sorry, I don't use freestyle jobs.